# C code explanation

Tags: c

There is a following function that is supposed to make a comparison between 2 floating point values, but faster than regular comparison in some specific cases (e.g. on Cortex-A8)

```
int isGreater(float* f1, float* f2)
{
    int i1, i2, t1, t2;

    i1 = *(int*)f1; // reading float as integer
    i2 = *(int*)f2; // reading float as integer

    t1 = i1 >> 31;
    i1 = (i1 ^ t1) + (t1 & 0x80000001);

    t2 = i2 >> 31;
    i2 = (i2 ^ t2) + (t2 & 0x80000001);

    return i1 > i2;
}
```

Can someone explain how does it exactly work?

Comment: "but faster." - faster than what?

Comment: I think you might be pulling this [out of its context a bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381927/efficient-floating-point-comparison-cortex-a8).

Comment: @Bart Yes, I just now got a moment to try this code in real situation, but I still don't understand how does it work.

Comment: [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) is worth a read.

Comment: @mouviciel It's great, but I'd like to have a step by step explanation if it is possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code exploits the structure of the IEEE 754 format for floating point numbers. The structure itself was specifically designed for such operations in order to make comparison operations fast.

Each single-precision IEEE 754 number has three parts (in order from MSB to LSB):

- sign bit
- exponent part (8 bits)
- significand of the mantissa (23 bits)

`f1` is greater than `f2` if:

- `f1` is positive and `f2` is negative
- `f1` and `f2` are both positive but `f1` has greater exponent than `f2`
- `f1` and `f2` are both positive and have the same exponents but `f1` has larger significand than `f2`
- the opposite of the previous two if `f1` and `f2` are negative

One could just compare both floating point numbers as integers if they were in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation. Unfortunately IEEE 754 doesn't use two's complement to represent negative numbers and that's why this code performs the conversion in order to be able to just compare the numbers as signed integers.

Here is a step by step commentary on what each line of code does:

```
i1 = *(int*)f1; // reading float as integer
i2 = *(int*)f2; // reading float as integer
```

This one uses the fact that on most 32-bit systems `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)` to read the floating point numbers into regular *signed* integer variables.

```
t1 = i1 >> 31;
```

This one extracts the sign bit of `f1`. If `f1` is negative its MSB would be `1` and hence `i1` would be negative. Shifting it 31 bits to the right preserves the sign and hence if `i1` was negative `t1` would have all bits set to `1` (equal to -1). If `f1` was positive its sign bit would be `0` and in the end `t1` would equal `0`.

```
i1 = (i1 ^ t1) + (t1 & 0x80000001);
```

If the sign bit was `1` this line would perform conversion to two's complement representation if `f1` was negative.

Here is how it works: if `f1` was positive, then `t1` is `0` and `(i1 ^ t1)` would just be `i1` and `(t1 & 0x80000001)` would be `0` and in the end `i1` would just retain its original value. If `f1` was negative then `t1` would have all bits set to `1` and the first expression on the RHS would be the bit inversion of `i1` and the second expression would equal `0x80000001`. This way `i1` would be converted to its bit inversion and `1` would be added. But this would lead to a positive number since the MSB would be cleared and that's why `0x80000000` is also added to keep the number negative.

```
t2 = i2 >> 31;
i2 = (i2 ^ t2) + (t2 & 0x80000001);
```

Perform the same as above for `f2`.

```
return i1 > i2;
```

Just compare the two resulting *signed* integers. Most CPUs have dedicated instructions to perform signed comparison in hardware.